# Web Query VBA Refresh

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

If I have a web query connection established, what's the best way to update the URL and refresh the connection with VBA?

Here is basically what I want to do:

```
Sub RefreshWebQuery()

    Dim request As String
    request = 'some url constructed by concatenating cell values

    'set command text of my web query as request
    'update my query table

End Sub
```

I've seen various methods online but none are concise/worked for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to refresh a query is by setting `.Refresh BackgroundQuery := False`.  The refresh is supposed to refresh the results. Also you can set `.RefreshPeriod = 0`.

```
Sub webquery()
    Dim url As String
    url = "URL;http://test.com"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
        .Name = "Geocoder Query"
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once , in one of my solutions, I had to refresh the Web Query results within some macro execution, via VBA.

Simplest solution I found is

```
   'refresh data extracted from webpage
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Perhaps you could use this too.